# Moto G8 Power/sofiar softbricked, TWRP sees encrypted files

Tags: unbricking, aosp

I got a hold of a Moto G8 Power, it has no working OS (slot A is Lineage, slot B is arrow OS, neither works). Bootloader works, TWRP recovery works, bootloader is unlocked. The issue is anytime I try to wipe in TWRP or sideload a ROM, it fails half way with error “operation not permitted”. If I try to install ROM through TWRP, it fails trying to mount anything and if I try to browse files in TWRP, all I see is files/folders with hash names.

I don’t know what to do with this, so it’s a last resort post before I throw it into ewaste bin. I’m not skilled at all with ROM loading on Android, please ELI5. Official ROM would be nice, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of your device is encrypted try, formating your data partition.

Comment: Hello. OP mentioned this in the question: "*anytime I try to wipe in TWRP or sideload a ROM, it fails half way with error “operation not permitted”*". You might want to provide a resolution for this.